# Fortran MPI fails when more than 2 threads on a 4 processors computer

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, fortran, mpi, openmpi

I'm working on a paralleled dynamic programing problem. My weird problem of MPI is that when I parallel using more than 2 processors, there comes the error.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
```

When I'm using 2 processors, the code can run with some problem in results (I'll specify after the code that can replicate the problem). Here's a list of compilers, OS info:

```
OS: Linux Ubuntu 14.04 
Fortran compiler: gfortran 4.8.4 + OpenMPI(mpif90) 1.10.0
```

And the simplified code: main:

```
PROGRAM main
USE UPDATE_VFUN 
IMPLICIT NONE    
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nz=2,nb=2,nk=2,nxi=2,nnb=2,nnk=2,nnb_b=2,nnk_b=2,itmax=4 
INTEGER:: myid, extra,numprocs,chunksize,indtop,indbot
INTEGER,PARAMETER:: N=2*nb*nk*nxi*nz*nz
REAL(8):: vc_ub(N), vc_b(N),vx(N),dist
CALL MPI_INIT(ierr) 
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr) 
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr) 

chunksize=int(real(N)/real(numprocs))
extra=N-chunksize*numprocs
IF (myid<extra) THEN
    indtop=myid*(chunksize+1)+1
    indbot=(myid+1)*(chunksize+1)
ELSE
    indtop=extra*(chunksize+1)+(myid-extra)*chunksize+1
    indbot=extra*(chunksize+1)+(myid-extra+1)*chunksize
END IF

DO i=1,itmax
    IF (dist>stp_rule) THEN
       CALL vupdate(vc_ub,vc_b,vx,dist,indtop,indbot)
       PRINT *, "Current Iteration", i, "in thread", myid
       PRINT *, "DISTANCE",dist
    ELSE
       EXIT
    END IF
END DO
CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
END PROGRAM main
```

And the external MODULE UPDATE_VFUN:

```
MODULE UPDATE_VFUN
USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS

    SUBROUTINE vupdate(vc_ub,vc_b,vx,dist,indtop,indbot)
    REAL(8), INTENT(INOUT):: vc_ub(:), vc_b(:), vx(:)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: indtop,indbot
    REAL(8), INTENT(OUT) :: dist
    INTEGER :: mychunk,N
    REAL(8) :: vc_ub_temp(size(vc_ub)),vc_b_temp(size(vc_b)),&
    vx_temp(size(vx))
    REAL(8),DIMENSION(indbot-indtop+1) :: myvc_ub,myvc_b,myvx

    N=size(vc_ub)
    mychunk=indbot-indtop+1

    myvc_ub=1.0d3
    myvc_b=1.2d4 
    myvx=1.2d2

    CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(myvc_ub,mychunk,MPI_REAL,vc_ub_temp,N,MPI_REAL,&
    MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(myvc_b,mychunk,MPI_REAL,vc_b_temp,N,MPI_REAL,&
    MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(myvx,mychunk,MPI_REAL,vx_temp,N,MPI_REAL,& 
    MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

    !Calculate distance
    dist=max(maxval(abs(vc_ub-vc_ub_temp)),maxval(abs(vc_b- &
    vc_b_temp)),maxval(abs(vx-vx_temp)))

    !Updating
    vc_ub=vc_ub_temp
    vc_b=vc_b_temp
    vx=vx_temp
 END SUBROUTINE vupdate

END MODULE UPDATE_VFUN
```

If I specify

```
mpirun -np 4
```

in makefile, the above error happens. If I specify `-np 2`, the program can run. But in print outs:

```
     vc_ub        vc_b    vx  
 [1]    1000      12000   120 
 [2]    1000      12000   120 
 ...        ...    ...
 [16]   1000      12000   120 
 [17] machine zero machine zero machine zero 
 ...        ...    ...
 [32] machine zero machine zero machine zero 
 SAME PATTERN FOR 33-48, AND 49-64.
```

It seems that the computer takes `chunksize=16` as if there are 4 processors. But with `-np 2`, shouldn't that be 32?

To sum up, my two questions are:
  (1) why in this case, `-np 4` cannot work, while `-np 2` can? 
  (2) why `-np 2` produces such goofy results?

Many thanks for your thoughts and comments!

Comment: We miss gfortran and openmpi versions. What is the value of N in the module, because it is not shared, is it? Finally, does the app generate a core? What does gdb sy bout when using the where command?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @redcrash. I've added version numbers in the question now. You're right about the `N` and it was in another GLOBVAR module, which I abstracted away here. I'll modify the code correspondingly. For the last two of your questions, I'm not sure I understand it...Could you be a bit more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Your output does not match any of the IO in your program? Your allgathers are definitely wrong, see: http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node69.html#Node69 "Note that the recvcount argument at the root indicates the number of items it receives from each process, not the total number of items it receives." Also note, that with your distribution of the remainde you can not use MPI_allgather, instead you should use MPI_allgatherV, though in your examples with extra=0 this should not matter. To compute the extra elements I'd avoid reals and stick with modulo and integer division.

Comment: I didn't try to understand the code so far, but since you use `real(8)` (which is a bad idea BTW) for your type, you (most probably) need to use `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` instead of `MPI_REAL`. Try this first.

Comment: What is `extra` initialized to?

Comment: @Ross: apparently `extra=N-chunksize*numprocs`